# How to prevant request by guzzle get redirected by client?

Tags: guzzle

How to prevant request by guzzle get redirected by client?

[screnshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB80V.png)

i already give the parameter allow_redirects set to false but still my request get redirected.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
  'headers' => [
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
  ], 'verify' => false
]);
$response = $client->post(
  "{$value->url}/wp-json/apg/v1/webhooks",
  [
    'form_params' => [
      'token_auth'   => $this->setting->token_auth,
      'webhooks_type'=> 'theme',
      'theme'        => $theme,
      'url_download' => url('/storage/themes')
    ],
    'allow_redirects' => FALSE
  ]
);
$jsonResponse = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Your screenshot does not match with the problem you are asking, what is the issue the one which you are asking or the one in the screenshot

Comment: also have you tried to define the constant for `allow_redirects` by using `define("allow_redirects", \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS );`

Comment: @bhucho haven't tried that one, i'll give it a try

Comment: @bhucho my route is only for post method, but the guzzle get redirect to current url as get method that trigger error of route